# Best way to migrate SharePoint Workflow Manager Databases

Tags: sharepoint, workflow-manager-1.x

Here is a scenario that I would like to know best way to tackle it.

1. SharePoint 2013 Farm 5 servers (2 app, 2 web, 1 DB) -- Windows Server 2012
2. Workflow Manager Server (a standalone box) -- Windows Server 2012
3. Workflow Manager DB Server (a SQL shared box) -- Windows Server 2008

As part of the infrastructure upgrade - we are decommissioning Windows 2008 servers. I was told to move workflow manager databases out of Windows 2008.

What I found online are the articles pointing to WFM disaster recovery plan where we backup restore workflow DBs onto a different server, re-install workflow manager on a new server, and execute the WFM restore using PowerShell.

Without doing Workflow Manager installation or uninstall/re-stalling, is there a way (even possibility) to migrate just the 6 workflow databases to different DB server, and then update existing workflow manager DB connection strings?

Comment: Based on the posts on MSFT forums, I followed my an approach and posted the solution here:   [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/251274/migrating-workflow-manager-databases-to-new-server.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of the updating the WFM databases. You need to setup new WFM servers and use backup and restore command to attach the 4 DBS. Check the details here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29158.workflow-manager-disaster-recovery.aspx

Comment: Yes I followed the disaster recovery steps and I have successfully migrated the WFM databases from one db server to another keeping the same WFM server.  The issue that I faced was existing workflow instances are broken (workflow status page throw error). So I had to restart the existing workflows. New workflow instances worked fine though.  It's a very complex process if you are doing it first time.